# NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone

How to use NSMutable Dictionary in another class for read and write data from plist file in iphone....

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find in in [NSDictionary reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), this class has a method to create a nsdictionary from a file `initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` . You can do something like:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDictionary" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Where myDictionary is your plist name (In case of your plist is inside resource bundle).
You can write a plist on disk with the method:

```
[dict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
```

Where filePath is your destination path.

Answer (score 0):

See the Plist files example on this [tutorial](http://www.iphoneexamples.com/).

```
// Look in Documents for an existing plist file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
    [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.plist", plistName] ];
[myPlistPath retain];

// If it's not there, copy it from the bundle
NSFileManager *fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ( ![fileManger fileExistsAtPath:myPlistPath] ) {
    NSString *pathToSettingsInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
        pathForResource:plistName ofType:@"plist"];
}


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectoryPath 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];


myKey = (int)[[plist valueForKey:@"myKey"] intValue];
myKey2 = (bool)[[plist valueForKey:@"myKey2"] boolValue];

[plist setValue:myKey forKey:@"myKey"];
[plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```